# How to glue all my apps together in Django?

Tags: django, django-apps

If my website is broken down into several apps, then what glues them together?
Does the chrome of my website needs to be an app, thereby my apps are within an app?

Answer (score 0):

Django apps are not like chrome. You put your Django apps in the settings.py file inside:

```
INSTALLED_APPS
```

You can use imports to access functions and classes from other apps.